# shell script : nested loop and continue

Tags: shell, continue

```
while [condition]
do
  for [condition]
  do
    if [ "$x" > 3 ];then
      break
    fi
  done

  if [ "$x" > 3 ];then
    continue
  fi
done
```

In the above script I have to test `"$x" > 3` twice. Actually the first time I test it, if it is true I want to escape the while loop and continue to the next while loop.

Is there any simpler way so I can use something like `continue 2` to escape the outer loop?

Comment: Why not use `continue 2` in the inner loop?

Comment: yes `continue n` . Also are you sure about ` for [ condition ] `... usually it `for n in a b c` or similar. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

"break" and "continue" are close relatives of "goto" and should generally be avoided as they introduce some nameless condition that causes a leap in the control flow of your program. If a condition exists that makes it necessary to jump to some other part of your program, the next person to read it will thank you for giving that condition a name so they don't have to figure it out!

In your case, your script can be written more succinctly as:

```
dataInRange=1
while [condition -a $dataInRange]
do
  for [condition -a $dataInRange]
  do
    if [ "$x" > 3 ];then
      dataInRange=0
    fi
  done
done
```